# Can WPAdBlock be a child of WPSideBar?

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I want to markup my ads with schema.org microdata, but my ads reside inside a sidebar (which I think is typical?) and sometimes even within the main content. As far as I can see WPAdBlock is a sibling of WPSideBar. So my question is, can you nest WPPageElements like that (placing the WPAdBlock inside the WPSideBar e.g.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter how you nest elements in Microdata, *unless* you use a property (`itemprop`).

These two snippets produce the **same** Microdata:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar">
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPAdBlock">
</div>
```

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar">

  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPAdBlock">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense. I could not find this info in the 'official' pages though.